# How do I implement in-app purchases in Monodroid?

Tags: in-app-purchase, xamarin.android, xamarin

I’m trying to add in-app purchases to my Monodroid application. Has anyone successfully implemented this in their app?

- I found the project [AndroidInAppBillingDemo](https://github.com/prashantvc/InAppBillingDemo), but I’m not sure how to integrate this into my app.
- I also found [an article on Google Play Services](http://blog.xamarin.com/introducing-the-google-play-services-component-for-xamarin-android/) which mentions in-app purchases, but I can’t find any example of how to do it.
- I also found [play.billing.v3](https://github.com/ddebilt/play.billing.v3). Has anyone successfully used this in their application?